# question on c++ object construction and scope

Tags: c++, constructor, scope

this is a little bit difficult to put into words, here is the snippet,

```
int main() {
    int i = 5;
    {
        int i(i);
        i = i+5;
//        int i = i;
//        i = i + 5;

        cout << "inner scope" << endl;
        cout << i << endl;
    }
    cout << "outer scope" << endl;
    cout << i << endl;
}
```

this give the correct output

```
inner scope
10
outer scope
5
```

But if I do this,

```
int main() {
    int i = 5;
    {
      //int i(i);
      //i = i+5;
        int i = i;
        i = i + 5;

        cout << "inner scope" << endl;
        cout << i << endl;
    }
    cout << "outer scope" << endl;
    cout << i << endl;
}
```

This throws an runtime exception, and gives wrong output,

```
inner scope
-858993455
outer scope
5
```

I feel this seems to be jsomething to do with the difference in the sequence of calling of copy constructor and assignment constructor, but I am not entirely sure, please enlighten me.

Comment: With the 2nd one I get `warning: 'i' is used uninitialized [-Wuninitialized]`.

Comment: Wildgues (and probably wrong) is that it is because of the order of things. In ```int i(i)``` you use the outter i which exists in the inner loop to construct a new i.  in ```int i=i``` you first create a variable i, and then try to assign it to i, which obviously is not the outter i beacuse the inner one has already been defined.

Comment: [Gcc](https://wandbox.org/permlink/fdcYCIp1bdnWaW57) (and clang) give *uninitialized* warning for both cases.

Comment: @songyuanyao you didn't initialize j for the outer scope, but the point is still valid.

Comment: @songyuanyao so I guess this is a bug of vs2019 compiler?

Comment: @techolic [Same warnings](https://wandbox.org/permlink/JTWOxmLlIy8dy2Yk) though.

Comment: @tesla1060 I suppose this is [UB](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub), anything is possible. Then we can't say this is a bug, compilers are allowed to do anything they want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you shadow a variable you remove all trace of it within that scope, so:

```
int i = i;
```

This declares `i` to equal its (uninitialized) self. This variable is completely independent from the parent scope's `i`. This is effectively undefined behaviour.

Curiously the `int i(i)` approach uses the parent scope's `i` to initialize, though that's rather peculiar that it works out. It might not be defined behaviour though.

You should be using a different variable name if you need to relate these two somehow. You can shadow if there's no inter-dependency.

In other words:

```
int j = i;
```

Comment: `int i(i);` is the same as `int i = i;` for this purpose. Both are UB.